# Use html email template and replace variables in MailMessage

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailmessage

I have an html email template in a file and want to replace variables in the template before sending the email. Is there any easy/built-in way of doing that or do I have to read the file contents as a string and replace them manually? It feels like AlternateView is made for loading a template but I can't find a way to replace variables.

```
    private void SendMail() {
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "host here";
        client.Port = 123;

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("from@test.com", "Test sender");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@test.com", "Test reciever"));
        message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = "Test subject";

        // testFile.html contents:
        //
        // <html>
        //  <body>
        //   <h1><%= name %></h1>          <-- Name should be replaced
        //  </body>
        // </html>
        var alternativeView = new AlternateView("testFile.html", new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));

        message.AlternateViews.Add(alternativeView);

        client.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
```

Comment: "or do I have to read the file contents as a string and replace them manually" yes. There's a lot of ways to do that.

Comment: There is unfortunately no other way but to write your own code which contains `String.Replace(...)`. AlternativeViews is used for providing the mail in Html and OnlyText/RichText, so it won't be scrambled if automatically converted

Comment: If you have control over the templates and it is a more complex scenario, you could use a templating engine like Liquid. There are packages available that help in expanding the templates, but they also have their complexities. In a small application, loading manually and using `string.Replace` might be the easiest and quickest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no built-in way to do this so I ended up reading the file as a string and replacing them manually (the reason I use AlternateView is because in the original code I have both an html and plain text body):

```
    private async Task SendMail() {
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "host here";
        client.Port = 123;

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("from@test.com", "Test sender");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@test.com", "Test reciever"));
        message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = "Test subject";

        // testFile.html contents:
        //
        // <html>
        //  <body>
        //   <h1><%= name %></h1>          <-- Name should be replaced
        //  </body>
        // </html>

        var content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("testFile.html");
        content = content.Replace("<%= name %>", "Superman");
        var alternativeView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content, new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

        message.AlternateViews.Add(alternativeView);

        await client.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to read template from file and then apply replace

Answer (score 1):

Consider [FluentEmail.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentEmail.Core/3.0.2?_src=template) which makes replacing tokens in a string used to send email simple.

Here is an example where `email.Data.Body` becomes the body for an email.

[image]

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        /*
         * Can come from a file
         */
        string template = @"
<html>
 <body>
  <h1><%= ##Name## %></h1>
  <p>On <%=##Date##%> you are required to change your password</p>
  <p>Any questions contact ##Contact##</p>
 </body>
</html>
";

        var email = Email
            .From("fromEmail")
            .To("toEmail")
            .Subject("subject")
            .UsingTemplate(template, new
            {
                Name = "Mary Sue", 
                Date = new DateTime(2022,10,12).ToString("d"),
                Contact = "Bill Jones (504) 999-1234"
            });

        Console.WriteLine(email.Data.Body); // for body of email

    }
}
```